# Java- Using a constructor to place in values for a method?

Tags: java, class, constructor, instance

I have two classes here:

```
public class Invoice {

    ArrayList<Double> ItemPrices= new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Boolean> ItemIsPet = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    ArrayList<Integer> ItemQuantitys = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void add(Item anItem){

    }


    public static void main(String args[]){

        int counter = 0;
        boolean pet;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {

            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Item " + counter+1 + ":");
            System.out.println();

            System.out.print("Please enter the item's price: ");
            double inputprice = s.nextDouble();

            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Is this item a pet? (Y/N): ");
            String inputIsPet = s.next();
            if (inputIsPet.equals('Y')){
                pet = true;
            }
            else {
                pet = false;
            }
            System.out.println();

            System.out.print("What is the quantity of this item?: ");
            int inputquantity = s.nextInt();


            Item newItem = new Item(inputprice, pet, inputquantity);

            counter += 1;

        } while (true);

    }
}
```

And here is the second class:

```
public class Item {

    Invoice Inv = new Invoice();

    public Item(double price, boolean isPet, int quantity){

    }

}
```

My question is for this line right here:

```
Item newItem = new Item(inputprice, pet, inputquantity);
```

So I have those 3 necessary arguments from the user input so that I can make a new object `newItem` of type item, but my question is once I have object `newItem`, how can I access those inputted arguments? My assignment is forcing me to implement this particular "add" method:

```
public void add(Item anItem)
```

Basically, the way I want to use this method is to take the inputted arguments from here:

```
Item newItem = new Item(inputprice, pet, inputquantity);
```

and have the "add" method access them, and from there put them into these arrays:

```
ArrayList<Double> ItemPrices= new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Boolean> ItemIsPet = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
ArrayList<Integer> ItemQuantitys = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

But how do I access the parts of the object `newItem`? Do I have to modify my constructor in some way?

Comment: Add instance fields and getters to the Item class and you are good to go

Comment: Are those arrays part of your assignment? I'd guess not, because they look very clunky and un-OO.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I have to modify my constructor in some way?

Yes, you need to save incoming values into instance fields.

```
public class Item {

    private final double price;
    private final boolean isPet;
    private final int quantity;

    public Item(double price, boolean isPet, int quantity) {
        this.price = price;
        this.isPet = isPet;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

}
```

> How can I access those inputted arguments?

Then you can write a getter for each field you want to access to.

```
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
```

> How do I access the parts of the object `newItem`?

Now you can.

```
double price = newItem.getPrice();
```

Comment: @MatthewButner, you may accept the answer if it was helpful